# Como passar a SESSION para uma variavel em php

Tags: php

Olá. Queria saber como posso passar o codigo da $_SESSION para uma variavel

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['codigoUsu']) ) {
    $codigoUsuario=$_SESSION['codigoUsu'];    
    inserirVenda($codigoUsuario,$codigoProduto);  
    header("Location: produtosSelecionados.php"); 
}
```

Pergunta editada

**controleVenda**

```
<?php

include 'crudVenda.php';
session_start();
 $opcao=$_GET['opcao'];
 if($opcao=="selecionar"){
            $codigoProduto=$_GET['codigoProduto'];  
                if(isset($_SESSION['codigoUsu'])){
                    $codigoUsu=$_SESSION['codigoUsu'];
                    inserirVenda($codigoUsu,$codigoProduto);  

                }    

                header("Location: produtosSelecionados.php"); 




}?>
```

**crudVenda**

```
<?php
 include 'conexaoBD.php';
function inserirVenda($codigoUsuario,$codigoProduto){
    conectar();
    query("INSERT INTO venda (codigoProduto,codigoUsuario) VALUES ($codigoProduto,$codigoUsuario)");
    fechar();

}
?>
```

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona em seu trecho de código? Vais usar esta variável em outro lugar? Estas iniciando a secção na página **produtosSelecionados.php**? Já tentou dar um `var_dump()` na sua variável?

Comment: eu pego esse $codigoUsuario e insiro no banco e ele vai para essa pagina onde selecionou esse produto. Mas esta dando um erro onde ele diz q n reconhece o codigoUsu. Estou iniciando a sessao em outra pagina de controle.

Comment: Eu tenho uma pagina onde estão os produtos a selecionar. Clicando la ele vai para o controleVenda que é a pagina onde eu pego oque é mandado da pagina que tem os produtos selecionaveis. Nessa pagina de controle eu preciso pegar o codigo do usuario via sessão para mandar para funcão e inserir no banco

Comment: É preciso por aspas simples nas variáveis presentes no VALUES do comando sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sua sessão não possui o codigoUsu, certifique-se de que a sua query está retornando esse código do usuário ao logar (imagino que seja um ID na tabela). Você pode tentar algo do tipo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <tblUsers> WHERE <condition>";
```

Assumindo que essa tabela possui o codigoUsu (ou um ID, melhor dizendo), use um `fetch_array()` (ou semelhante) para transformar o resultado da query em um array, e armazene em uma variável dita auxiliar. Após isso, você apenas precisa chamar a variável auxiliar e indicar o `index` (ou key) desse array nela, por exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$senha'";
$queryResult = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) == 1): //Se só 1 usuário for encontrado
$auxiliar = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult);
echo $auxiliar['ID'];
```

Para checar os indexes que existem na sua `$auxiliar`, verifique com `var_dump();`.

Answer (score 0):

Em todas as páginas que irão utilizar $_SESSION você deve startar a função abaixo.

```
session_start();
```

Comment: É de praxe e sempre bom caso a sessão não esteja sendo inicializada por uma biblioteca  colocar um `if ( !isset($_SESSION) ) {}` para verificar a variável global pois uma página pode estar carregando outras que já contém uma chamada para instanciar a secção.

Comment: O problema é que ele nao esta inserindo no banco